# Create Chart Showing Trend for Binary Outcome Variables Vs Date in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, charts

I have a dataset with several hundred rows showing whether I completed tasks on a given day. For both task1 and task2, I would mark a 1 if I did and 0 if I did not. An example of 5 rows is below.

```
Date    task1   task2
1/1/20  1       0
2/1/20  0       0
3/1/20  1       1
4/1/20  1       1
5/1/20  1       1
...
```

I'm looking to create a chart that would have the date on the x axis and the two variables on the y. Then using two different colours (green for 1 and white for 0) I would see how often I completed each task. I would also like to label the different parts of the chart to show the total days in a row that the tasks are completed (or not).

An image below gives an idea of what I want it to look like (note I have much more data than 3 obs per a month)  [image]

Comment: Just realised something - is a zero in your chart showing just one day a task wasn't done?
I assume the white areas are days that a task wasn't done, so you can't really have zeroes, can you?

Answer (score 0):

Not yet an answer, but I've started to get it resolved.  I've got the value of each run identified.
See a very rough sample sheet here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qq1XRLNFIGunbwqhy5o-zP6NZbaEVFfvLGIRhOquxo4/edit?usp=sharing

Column H has the values for each run (for Task1) - positive for a run of "1"s, and negative for a run of "0"s.  Haven't figured out how to plot them both on the same line.

The conditional formatting with green highlighting flags each row that needs to be plotted, due to a change in the run value.

I'll see if I can generate a chart from this...